# Weird Visual Studio 2015 Designer Errors

Tags: c#, wpf

When i first open Visual Studio and my solution i see these errors in designer;

-Invalidvalueforproperty 'Command': 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue'

-The component 'RatingControlSample.RatingControl' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/RatingControl;component/ratingcontrol.xaml'

I can see my application's gui without any problem in designer. I just see an error image on rating control. I can build,compile and run my application without any problem. When i rebuild solution errors disappear. But when i make changes in xaml file errors reappear.

In designer first error points this line;

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
```

In designer second error points rating control definition.

I'm using this custom control called rating control and you can find it here : http://nickeandersson.blogs.com/blog/2008/02/a-rating-contro.html
I just imported it's dll file.

The first error is not about rating control and i'm targeting x86.

Why these errors appear?